# Can I work in Switzerland with a French Carte de sejour? I am an Indian national married to a French citizen

Tags: switzerland

I recently moved from India to France to be with my Husband. We live in an area which is covered under the Swiss 'G-Permit'. I am just beginning to learn French. Is it possible for me to get this permit to be able to work in Switzerland?

Comment: Please don't create duplicate accounts. Contact us about getting access to your original account. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/en/home/themen/aufenthalt/nicht_eu_efta/ausweis_g__grenzgaengerbewilligung.html

> Third-country nationals will only be given a cross-border commuter
>   G-permit, if they have a permanent residence permit in a neighboring
>   country. They also need to have had their residence in the neighboring
>   country’s border zone for at least six months and fulfill the labor
>   market requirements. G-permits are usually valid for one year, and are
>   limited to the border zone of the issuing canton. Third-country border
>   commuters require permission to change jobs or occupations.

I'd guess the answer is no, depending on your definition of recent. You need to have lived there for 6 months.

After that it depends on whether you have permanent residence or only temporary work contracts.

Comment: (+1) Unless I am mistaken, EU law and the bilateral agreements don't apply to this situation (it would be different if the French citizen was living in Switzerland or possibly even if the husband was an EU citizen other than French). Consequently, the “labor market requirements” clause is likely to be much more of a hurdle and the French residence permit doesn't help much.